# Then function is not working properly in my controller

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularJS I can't display the response in front-end that I get from back-end after POST function, actually the post function works right but I cant get the response `.then()` function not working.

CONTROLLER:

```
$scope.AddNewDepartment = function() {  //my function in controller.js
    var PostDeptDetails = {             //variable to post a data in database
        organization_id: OrgId,
        department_name: $scope.DepartmentText
    };

    MasterCreationFactory.PostDepartment(PostDeptDetails).then(function(response) { //MasterCreationFactory-My factory service name

        alert(response);
    });
};
```

I dint get any response in alert I have also tried `response.data`.

SERVICES:

```
MasterCreationFactory.PostDepartment = function(PostDeptDetails) { //MasterCreationFactory -factory name in service.js
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: baseurl + '/Department',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        data: PostDeptDetails
    });
};
```

Comment: do you get an error  in your console ?

Comment: yes (error:unexpected error I)

Comment: your code is hard to read and incomplete. what you can do is to try to replicate the use case in a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OF044j?p=preview) and post it inside your question

Comment: i have edited my code for ur understanding please check

Comment: Is the request fired or do you get the error before?

Comment: post request is working fine

Comment: MasterCreationFactory.PostDepartment(PostDeptDetails) upto this it works, i cant get the response after posting, that is .then(function(response)  // this function doesnt work what could be the mistake?

Comment: Add a second function to `then`: `.then(function () {}, function (error) { console.log(error); }` and see what you get.

Comment: ya it showing error in console